# Augment struct parsed with json with variable

Tags: json, swift

I have some static data for a list of "Badges" that I'm able to parse with JSONDecoder. I want to add a state that is not in the json data and when I added the variable to the Badge struct, parsing failed.

I then tried to create a two different structs, BadgeData which is parsed and Badge which contains state variable and BadgeData. But how do I merge this with state variable in a good way? Is there a better structure for this?

```
import Foundation


final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var badges: [Badge] = // ??
    
    var badgeData: [BadgeData] = load("badges.json")
    var taken: [Int] = load("taken.json")
}

struct BadgeData: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    
    let title: String
    let imageRef: String
    let requirements: [Requirement]
}

struct Badge: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let data: BadgeData
    var id: Int {
        data.id
    }
    
    var isTaken: Bool
}

struct Requirement: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    
    let title: String
    let detail: String
}
```

Comment: Create a CodingKey enum containing the keys you want the decoder to include when decoding the json. And also give your isTaken property a default value. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 1):

> when I added the variable to the Badge struct, parsing failed.

You need [coding keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Defining coding keys allows you to determine which properties you get from JSON and which are ignored

```
struct Badge: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    
    let title: String
    let imageRef: String
    let requirements: [Requirement]
    
    var isTaken: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey 
    {
    case id
    case title
    case imageRef
    case requirements
    }
}
```

The cases in `CodingKeys` map one to one to the properties you want to deserialise from the JSON.

Note also, that `CodingKeys` has a raw type which is `String`. This means that you can have different keys in your JSON to the property names e.g.

```
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey 
    {
    case id
    case title
    case imageRef = "image_ref"
    case requirements
    }
```

would mean that the `imageRef` property in the object comes from the `image_ref` property in the JSON.